# How to obtain curl exec response

Tags: php, curl, response

I am developing a PHP script that:

1. Gets 10 rows from DB (works well)
2. Sends addresses from these rows to Map API
3. Obtains data
4. Save results in DB (works well)

> I don't know how to obtain the final response of curl_exec.  curl_exec
>   in $response = call('GET', $query);
>    - even when hasn't completed returns something in response.

These my loop that is waiting for the response of the call function. But it doesn't work json_decode($stringJSON) is invoked earlier than it is obtained the final response

```
$requestHandled = false;
$response = "";

$response = call('GET', $query);
while(!$requestHandled) {
    if(strlen($response) > 5){

        $response = mb_convert_encoding($response, "UTF-8");
        $stringJSON = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($response) : $response;
        echo $stringJSON;

        $jsonObject = "+";
        echo $jsonObject;

        $jsonObject = json_decode($stringJSON);

        echo $jsonObject;

        $requestHandled = true;
    }
}
```

This is my curl call function

```
function call($method, $url, $data = false) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    if ($data) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
        $headers[] = 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    return curl_exec($ch);
```

Please help. Has spent a half of the day solving it

Comment: Your `call()` function will block for as long as curl is busy fetching the response, so the `while` loop is pointless. What is the output of `var_dump( $response );`, if you put it just after `$response = call('GET', $query);`? Also, do you have some kind of error logging mechanism set up? If not: you should, as it's the minimum requirement for debugging. If you already have: check your logs to see if you find any problem pertaining to your curl calls.

Comment: There are no errors in my logs and call function works well, I just can't catch the final response and decode it into a php variable. I added var_dump( $response ); after $response = call('GET', $query); 
Now I see : 
1) " " - result of var_dump( $response );
2)  $jsonObject = json_decode($stringJSON);
decodes " " -> nothing
3) Only after a few seconds stingJson appears in " "

Comment: seems something wrong happens during fetching in curl_exec... try this  ```function call($method, $url, $data = NULL) {
 require_once ('hhb_.inc.php');
 $hc = new hhb_curl ();
 $hc->_setComfortableOptions ();
 $hc->setopt ( CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method );
 if ($data) {
  $hc->setopt_array ( array (
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array (
      'Content-Type: application/json',
      'Content-Length: ' . strlen ( $data ) 
    ),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data 
  ) );
 }
 $hc->exec ( $url );
 hhb_var_dump ( $hc->getStdErr (), $hc->getStdOut () );
 return $hc->getStdOut ();
}```

Comment: with hhb_curl from https://github.com/divinity76/hhb_.inc.php/blob/master/hhb_.inc.php - what does hhb_var_dump say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the result of the `var_dump( $response )` is an empty string?

In that case, it simply means the response from the server is empty, because I just tested your function `call()` and it seems to work just fine. In other words, make sure the URL (with the method GET) you are trying to call actually returns data to begin with.

I wouldn't be surprised if you simply have a typographical error somewhere in the URL.

Also, for debugging purposes, temporarily replace

```
return curl_exec($ch);
```

with

```
$result = curl_exec($ch); 
var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
return $result;
```

and investigate the info in the `var_dump()` result, to make sure the response code is `200` (or any other that indicates success) and not in the `4xx` or `5xx` ranges (respectively indicating either a client or server error), for instance.

See [`curl_getinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/function.curl-getinfo.php) for more information about what useful information will be returned about your last `curl` transfer.

---

To address OPs comment(s):

Please try this complete script (nothing else: no `while` loop, no `stripslashes()`, no `json_decode()`, etc):

```
<?php

function call($method, $url, $data = false) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    if ($data) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
        $headers[] = 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch); 
    var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch)); // check this result and make sure the response code is 200
    return $result;
}

$query = 'fill in the correct URL! (with http(s)://)';

$response = call('GET', $query);
var_dump( $response ); // check this result and see if it's an empty string
die;
```

If the `var_dump( $response );` returns an empty string, it means your script works fine but the URL you are calling simply returned an empty response.

If `$response` is **not** empty and actually contains JSON data, replace

```
var_dump( $response );
```

with

```
$stringJSON = mb_convert_encoding( $response, "UTF-8" );

echo $stringJSON; // make sure this contains valid JSON data

// stripslashes() should not be needed

var_dump( json_decode( $stringJSON ) ); // if JSON data was valid, you should get a valid PHP data structure
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not going to click on your link (please edit your question if you want to share more code or use a well known online PHP tester (if they support curl, that is)), but I've given you additional advice in my answer.

Comment: var_dump( json_decode($stringJSON) ); returns NULL
then $stringJSON appears in echo $stringJSON;

Comment: when debugging a curl request, use CURLOPT_VERBOSE and CURLOPT_STDERR